# Mouse hover menu like the toolbar in visual studio

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to find out if its possible to implement a panel that pops up containing a datagrid the mouse hovers over the "expander" bit.

Looking for something that behaves like the toolbox in visual studio.

Im having major problems searching as im not really sure what its called.

Please let me know if I need to explain myself better.

Comment: ... you need to explain yourself better ;)

Comment: If you have visual studio the toolbox on the left hand side. I want something that behaves exactly the same as that but instead of having toolbox items in it I would like it to have a datagrid. Still need more explanation? I can do some screenshots if needs be :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/) to achieve this

[image]

this was done in XAML with the following code:

```
<avalondock:DockingManager x:Name="dockingManager">
    <avalondock:LayoutRoot>
        <avalondock:LayoutRoot.LeftSide>
            <avalondock:LayoutAnchorSide>
                <avalondock:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                    <avalondock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Autohidden Content">
                        <DataGrid>
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Col1"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Col2"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Col3"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </avalondock:LayoutAnchorable>
                </avalondock:LayoutAnchorGroup>
            </avalondock:LayoutAnchorSide>
        </avalondock:LayoutRoot.LeftSide>
    </avalondock:LayoutRoot>
</avalondock:DockingManager>
```

Comment: Thanks will have a look and test for suitability then mark as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I would facilitate WPF animations to realize any kind of menu that pops up / appears / slides in / come somehow into action smoothly.

Build your menu-control in any way you want e.g. based on a StackPanel and then assign some custom animations to its position properties to make it appear and disappear.

The use of animations is quite simple since you are only specifying for a particular property a begin value, a target value and way to do the transition between those two.

For example to make a Stackpanel grow and shrink you may do the following:

```
// suppose you have a stackpanel named sp.

// create the actual animation
DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
myDoubleAnimation.From = 100;
myDoubleAnimation.To = 300;
myDoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

// cerate the storyboard which comprise all your single animations into a compound animation - a storyboard.
StoryBoard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
myStoryboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);

// link the animation with the object it is supposed to work on
Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimation, sp.Name);

// specify the target property of ypur StackPanel which should be affected by the animation
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(Rectangle.Width));
```

For a complete introduction you may start reading here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx

Also read about Easing functions since with their help you can build much more sophisticated animations.